# Can you use variables in their own initialization line (tryGetOrElse in a dictionary)?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Consider the following code:

```
private Dictionary<RobotSettings, Trader> createTradersFor(IEnumerable<RobotSettings> settings)
{
    var traderSet = new Dictionary<Tuple<IGateway, IBroker>, Trader>();

    return settings.ToDictionary(s => s, s =>
    {
        var key = Tuple.Create(s.gateway, s.broker);

        Trader trader = traderSet.TryGetValue(key, out trader)
            ? trader
            : traderSet[key] = new Trader(s.gateway, s.broker);
        return trader;
    });
}
```

I'm talking specifically about the initialization of trader variable in a closure, which uses itself in the same line it is being instantiated.

I've been using that pattern of dealing with dictionaries a lot lately, cause I really don't like uninitialized variables :) and would like to know if this is even guaranteed to compile in the future.

Comment: Does this even compile now? TryGetValue returns bool and trader is of type Trader. That looks like a type mismatch to me.

Comment: This does compile, because the result of the complete ternary operator is assigned to `trader`. And the result of the ternary operator is without doubt of type `Trader`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside from looking very odd, there is nothing wrong with it - technically.
First, the declaration of `trader` will be executed, so there exists a Trader object without a value assigned.
Second, the `TryGetValue` part is evaluated and returns either true or false. If it returned true, the now assigned `trader` will be returned. If it returns false, a new Trader is created and added to the dictionary via an assignment operation. The result of an assignment operation is the value of the object that was assigned to. That is the new trader.
Third, the result of the ternary operator will be returned and assigned to `trader`.

It is unlikely that this will change in the future, because changing the order of evaluation of a statement like this is a very breaking change.

**UPDATE:**
Because it looks very odd, I would not use it. I would solve this problem by creating an extension method for `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` called `GetOrAdd`.
It could look like so:

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
                                            TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> creator)
{
    TValue value;
    if(!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = creator(key);
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var trader = traderSet.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Trader(s.gateway, s.broker));
```

This is **a lot** cleaner and it is even shorter than your odd looking approach.

BTW: You could use the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead. This class already has a method `GetOrAdd` and has the benefit of being thread safe.

Comment: Great idea for the extension method

Answer (score 2):

Guarantee is a strong word, but it's very, very, very unlikely that it will stop compiling in the future - the language teams strive to maintain backward compatibility and unless there's a huge paradigm shift (i.e., from VB6 to the first VB.NET), this code should continue building fine.

I actually think it's a nice trick, but it took me some time to see that TryGetValue was used in a ternary operation (and other people had the same problem), so you may be saving one line of code here (moving the trader declaration one line up), but there may be an extra maintenance cost to pay by you later (or whoever inherits this code), so maybe you should reconsider splitting the declaration...

```
Trader trader;
trader = traderSet.TryGetValue(key, out trader) ?
...
```

Comment: The only drawback is that you don't get intellisense on that line because the `trader` variable isn't declared yet. And it's a bit confusing imho.

Answer (score 1):

```
Trader trader = traderSet.TryGetValue(key, out trader)
    ? trader
    : traderSet[key] = new Trader(s.gateway, s.broker);
```

vs.

```
Trader trader;
if (!traderSet.TryGetValue(key, out trader)) {
    trader = traderSet[key] = new Trader(s.gateway, s.broker);
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing either, although I'm not sure it's any better than the straightforward alternative that doesn't require future programmers to work out what the code does.